# Adding a name value pair to an array object in JSON using JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, json, crud

I want to implement this :
"Check the key name default  is available or not, if available then add one more key in same object. => ("pin" : 91) " on the json given below. I have tried the following code.

```
var myObj = {
     "data": [{
         "code": "EN",
         "language": "English",
         "content_available": true,
         "isdefault": true
     }, {
         "code": "AR",
         "language": "Arabic",
         "content_available": true,
         "isdefault": false,
                "default" : true

     }, {
         "code": "BR",
         "language": "Brazilian Portuguese",
         "content_available": true,
         "isdefault": false
     }, {
         "code": "CN",
         "language": "Simplified Chinese",
         "content_available": true,
         "isdefault": false,
                "default" : true
     }, {
         "code": "TW",
         "language": "Traditional Chinese",
         "content_available": true,
         "isdefault": false
     }, {
         "code": "DE",
         "language": "German",
         "content_available": true,
         "isdefault": false
     }, {
         "code": "ES",
         "language": "Spanish",
         "content_available": true,
         "isdefault": false
     }, {
         "code": "FR",
         "language": "French",
         "content_available": true,
         "isdefault": false
     }, {
         "code": "JP",
         "language": "Japanese",
         "content_available": true,
         "isdefault": false,
                 "default" : true
     }, {
         "code": "RU",
         "language": "Russian",
         "content_available": false,
         "isdefault": false
     }],
     "success": true
 }
function addKey(k) {
  for (var key in myObj.data) {
    if (myObj["data"][key] === k) {
      myObj["data"][key]["pin"] = "91";
    }
  }
}
addKey("default");
console.log(myObj);
```

Comment: `myObj["data"]` is an array, `myObj["data"][key]` is an object. It can never be equal to the string `"default"`. Try `if (myObj["data"][key].hasOwnProperty(k))` instead.

Comment: Why not post this as the answer instead of a comment?

Comment: @Xufox this is giving me a syntax error!! :( says unexpected number.

Comment: @SylieC No, it isn’t. Neither my code nor your code contains a number literal anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is loop through the key names and if not present, create it. But, keep your types in mind. `for/in` is for iterating objects, not arrays and `forEach()` is preferred for arrays.

```js
var myObj = {
     "data": [{
         "code": "EN",
         "language": "English",
         "content_available": true,
         "isdefault": true
     }, {
         "code": "AR",
         "language": "Arabic",
         "content_available": true,
         "isdefault": false,
                "default" : true

     }, {
         "code": "BR",
         "language": "Brazilian Portuguese",
         "content_available": true,
         "isdefault": false
     }, {
         "code": "CN",
         "language": "Simplified Chinese",
         "content_available": true,
         "isdefault": false,
                "default" : true
     }, {
         "code": "TW",
         "language": "Traditional Chinese",
         "content_available": true,
         "isdefault": false
     }, {
         "code": "DE",
         "language": "German",
         "content_available": true,
         "isdefault": false
     }, {
         "code": "ES",
         "language": "Spanish",
         "content_available": true,
         "isdefault": false
     }, {
         "code": "FR",
         "language": "French",
         "content_available": true,
         "isdefault": false
     }, {
         "code": "JP",
         "language": "Japanese",
         "content_available": true,
         "isdefault": false,
                 "default" : true
     }, {
         "code": "RU",
         "language": "Russian",
         "content_available": false,
         "isdefault": false
     }],
     "success": true
}

 
function addKey(k) {

  // myObj.data is an array. for/in loops should not be used on arrays
  // But forEach() is preferred on arrays
  myObj.data.forEach(function(obj){
    
    // Each array element is an object. We need to loop that object.
    // for/in loops are for objects
    for(var prop in obj){
      // Is the current property (key) name the same as the provided argument ("default")
      if(prop === k){
         // Add new key/value to the object
         obj["pin"] = "91";
      } 
    }
  });
}
addKey("default");
console.log(myObj);
```

Comment: these were some really good advises. Will definitely follow them in the future.. Thanks a lot, and yes this snippet works. :)

Comment: @SylieC Don't forget to up vote all helpful answers and to mark one as *"the"* answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkForKey(obj, key) {
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.data.length; i++) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(obj.data[i]) && obj.data[i][key] !== undefined) {
            obj.data[i].pin = 91;
        }
    }
}

checkForKey(myObj, 'default');
```

First, we get the data key. Since it's an array we iterate over it. Then, we check if default key has a defined value or not and add the key pin only when it has been defined with any value.

Comment: this gives me " Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'default' of undefined "